# How long until this date?

Tags: code-golf, date

The idea is this: Write a function to print the length of time from now/today's date (at the time the function is called) until a date supplied as an argument.

**Assumptions:**

- Input date will always be tomorrow or later, in the future.
- Input date will never be more than 10 years in the future.

**Rules:**

- Output must be in this format: "[z year(s)], [x month(s)], y day(s) until -Input Date-"
- Output time frame (day/month/year) must be pluralized correctly. i.e. `1 month`, not `1 months`
- Input can be in whichever date format *you* prefer (3/15/12 - March 15, 2012 - 2012.03.15).

**Example:**
Assuming program is run on March 15, 2012:

- Input date of `3/20/12` = `5 days until 3/20/12`
- *NOT* Input date of `4/16/12` = `1 month, 1 days until 3/20/12`
- Input date of `2012.04.20` = `1 month, 5 days until 2012.04.20`
- *NOT* Input date of `2012.04.20` = `36 days until 2012.04.20`
- Input date of `10/31/17` = `5 years, 7 months, 16 days until 10/31/17`
- Input date of `3/15/13` = `1 year until 3/15/13`

This is code golf, so shortest length code wins.

I suppose for the sake of having a deadline, I will be selecting an answer on:

### March 23, 2012!

(This is my first CG question, so I'll be happy to correct any question errors on my part!)

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha 10 chars: `now until <input time>`  :p

Comment: @Griffin 4 chars: `now-<input time>`

Comment: @PhiNotPi well played, good sir.

Comment: Is it okay to say "1 days until 3/16/12"?

Comment: @MrZander No. I'll update the question. If the number is 1, then there should be no pluralization.

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf.SE. Every question should be tagged to indicate the class of challenge that is being presented (i.e. if you mean the least characters you want [code-golf]), because we [entertain](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai-player) other [types](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) of [challenges](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) as well, as long as they have an objective winning standard. I'll do this one for you. BTW--Nicely specified.

Comment: How to work with leap yeras in answer? In 10 years then will be 2 days error. How long is month?

Comment: The month is as long as the calendar month. i.e. February 2012 has 29 days, February 2013 has 28.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### R, 99 characters

I know it is sort of cheating, but R is all about its packages and [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) is so convenient for this kind of tasks!

```
f=function(x){library(lubridate);cat(show(as.period(interval(mdy("3/15/2012"),mdy(x)))),"until",x)}
```

## Usage:

```
f("10/31/2017")
[1] 5 years, 7 months and 16 days 
5 years, 7 months and 16 days  until 10/31/2017
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/) + [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), 331 bytes

```python
from dateutil import*
from datetime import*
def f(s):
 if'/'in s:m,y,d=map(int,s.split('/'))
 else:y,m,d=map(int,s.split('.'))
 x=relativedelta.relativedelta(datetime(y,m,d),datetime.now())
 D,M,Y=x.days,x.months,x.years
 return f"{Y} year{'s'*(Y>1)}, "*(Y>0)+f"{M} month{'s'*(M>1)}, "*(M>0)+f"{D} day{'s'*(D>1)} "*(D>0)+"until "+s
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBA: <strike>766</strike> 631 Chars

Thanks to [mellamokb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/879/mellamokb) for helping shorten up the string creation and `IIf`.

```vba
Function k(i)
e=" month"
g="s"
n=Now()
r=Month(n)
s=Month(i)
t=DateSerial(Year(i),s,1)
u=DateSerial(Year(i),s-1,1)
v=Day(n)
w=Day(i)
x=DateSerial(Year(n),r,1)
d=t-u-v+w
For y=0 To 10
If Year(DateAdd("yyyy",-1*y,i))=Year(n) Then Exit For
Next
y=IIf(s=1,y-1,y)
z=s-r
z=IIf(z<0,z+12,z)
For m=0 To z
If Month(DateAdd("m",-1*m,i))=r Then Exit For
Next
d=IIf(v<=w,w-v,d)
m=IIf(v>w,m-1,m)
If y Then a=y & " year" & Left(g,y-1)
a=IIf((m Or d) And y,a & ",",a)
If m Then b=IIf(d,m & e & Left(g,m-1) & ",",m & e & Left(g,m-1))
If d Then c=IIf(d>1,d & " days",d & " day")
k=Trim(Trim(a & " " & b) & " " & c) & " until " & i & "."
End Function
```

I know `VBA` definitely does not lend itself to code golfing as well as some other languages, but it's what I'm good (not expert) at. :-)

This has been a fun exercise for me!

Comment: It's not entirely VBA's fault, there are some good ways to combine logic in your code :)  For example, `If y > 0 Then a = y & " year,":If y > 1 Then a = y & " years,"` could be combined together to `a = y & " year" & Left("s", y - 1) & ","`

Comment: @mellamokb Very good. I'll take a look at that and repost!

Comment: I had an issue with some test cases, namely `1 year`, `1 month`, `1 day`. I have corrected this in the answer. It actually made for shorter code!

Comment: And after posting the update, I see that I can change `If v < w Then d = w - v:If v = w Then d = 0` to `If v <= w Then d = w - v` for a savings of an additional 20 characters. I'll update the answer if I have a more significant change to post.

Comment: I imagine I can do this better with arrays... I will take another look and possibly add another answer...

Comment: I think that you could rewrite this using the `DateDiff` function to drastically lower your bytecount

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 315 characters

```
function p($z)
{
list($d,$m,$y)=explode("/",$z);
$d=$d-date("d");
$n=$m-1;
$m=$m-date("m")-($d<0);
$d=$d+($d<0)*($n>7^$n&1)+27+($n-2?3:($y%4?1:($y%100?2:($y%400?1:2))));
$y=$y-date("Y")-($m<0);
$s="s ";
echo ($y?$y." year".$s[$y<2]:"")." ".($m?$m." month".$s[$m<2]:"")." ".($d?$d." day".$s[$d<2]:"")." until ".$z;
}
```

Usage:

```
p("11/03/2006");
```

Takes dates in a `dd/mm/yyyy` format. I've used Griffin's month length calculation([again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3412/737)), though I had to stick extra brackets in it to make the precedence work properly. I've also left some line-breaks in to make it a little easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (213)

takes dates in any format `Date.parse` accepts. Tried just with `yyyy-mm-dd`

```rb
def u s
t=Date.today
f=Date.parse s
[[0,'year'],[0,'month'],[0,'day']].map{|c,n| while t<f 
c+=1
t=t.send"next_#{n}"
end
c,t=c-1,t.send("prev_#{n}")if t>f
[c,n+(c>1??s:'')]*' 'if c>0}.compact*', '+' until '+s
end
```

to also get weeks, add:

```rb
['prev_','next_'].each{|n|Date.send(:define_method,n+'week'){send n+'day',7}}
```

and `[0,'week'],` (between month and day). days will then always be `< 7`

Comment: which ruby version are you using.... I tried to run your code on ruby1.9.2p0, but it gives me error `uninitialized constant Object::Date (NameError)`... I think you are using the Rails `Date` class

Comment: @Rohit 1.9.3, not using Rails stuff. [Date rdoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)

Comment: I saw the doc earlier.. but was confused on the error I was getting... I am still unable to figure out why I am getting this error. I am on windows 7 64-bit, ruby192p0

Comment: @rohit try with 193?

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 151 chars

```php
function p($z){$n=date_create(date('Y-m-d'));$d=date_create($z);$i=date_diff($n,$d);print($i->format('%R%y years, %m months, and %a days until '.$z));}
```

Comment: It is missing the plurals and does not count correctly, because format() does not subtract the days from the months... I had a similar solution with PHP as well.

Comment: This is my PHP solution, but still lacks of the previously mentioned error: `echo date_diff(new DateTime(),new DateTime($argv[1]))->format('%yyears, %mmonths, %a days');` Its 92 chars long, when called on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 125 bytes

Since [the answer by Paolo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5227/22867) used an external library, I shall do the same. Node.js is all about NPM packages and [moment](http://momentjs.com/) + [HumanizeDuration](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js) is so convenient for this task!

#### Node environments

```js
m=require('moment'),f=d=>console.log(require('humanize-duration')(m(d).diff(m()),{units:['y','mo','d'],round:1})+' until '+d)
```

#### Browser environment

Since the libraries declare global variables, it's actually a bit shorter (102 bytes). It's not clear whether I need to include the script tags required to load in the third-party JavaScript, so I will count the Node one officially.

```js
f=d=>console.log(humanizeDuration((m=moment)(d).diff(m()),{units:['y','mo','d'],round:1})+' until '+d)
```

---

### CoffeeScript, also 125 bytes

```coffee
f=(d)->console.log require('humanize-duration')((m=require 'moment')(d).diff(m()),{units:['y','mo','d'],round:1})+' until '+d
```