# calculate days of a month

Tags: code-golf

I would like to see the shortest expression to calculate the days (or the last day)  of a month in any language.

Considering y as the number of year and m as month.

Basic rules

- without date / time functions.
- considering leap years.
- there is not other rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### C, <strike>40</strike> <strike>33</strike> 31 characters

Reduced length in three ways:
1. Replaced `m%2^m>7` with `m^m>7`. The first is 0/1 in 30/31 day months, the second is even/odd. But the high bits don't matter, because their all set in 30 anyway (months with 30/31 days look like a really good idea now).
2. Used mob's idea (`y%(y%100?4:400)` as a leap year test)
3. Used `<1` instead of `!` saves parenthesis.
4. `y%(y%100?4:400)` -> `y%(y%25?4:16)` - works the same.

```
m-2?30|m^m>7:28|y%(y%25?4:16)<1
```

Comment: `...:28+!(y%(y%100?4:400))` shaves 3 more

Comment: Thanks @mob, I'm taking it a bit further, will update soon.

Comment: If you're going to use `y%16`, why not `y%8`?

Comment: In fact, `(y%50?4:8)` or `(y%25?4:8)` work as well.

Comment: Thanks @mob, `%16` works. `%8` fails on 2200. I thought about `&15`, which isn't good, and somehow missed the equivalent `%16`

Comment: Good catch. I didn't have 2200 in my test cases.

Answer (score 5):

### C, <strike>47</strike> 45 characters

```
30+(m>7^m&1)-(m^2?0:2-!(y%100||(y/=100),y%4))
```

Taken from [an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3412/737) to an earlier question where I borrowed a couple of tricks from [another user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2501/griffin). Returns the length of month `m` in year `y` for the Gregorian calendar. [ugoren's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5041/737) to the same question is shorter and may give a shorter answer to this question.

With thanks to [mob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5202/mob) for his leap year calculation.

Comment: Here's another trick: use the expression `!(y%100||(y/=100),y%4)`

Comment: @mob Wow. It's taken me a good fifteen minutes to figure out how that works (I even checked it on ideone to make sure it did). Clever.

Comment: Figured out a better one: `!(y%(y%100?4:400))`

Comment: @mob I think I'll leave mine as it is now - there's no way I'll catch up with ugoren's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've already answered it before in stackoverflow:

```
(62648012>>m*2&3)+28+(m==2&&y%4==0)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675720/calculate-days-of-month/11675530#11675530

[EDIT] 
Matt advertised me about leap yars below and he's asked about language. About the language: the expression works on c/c++ and maybe others.

So, the simplest form will work until 2100... but to prevents the 2100 bug :) I've copied the Matt solution to leap year:

```
(62648012>>m*2&3)+28+(m==2&&(y%4==0&&(y%100!=0||y%400==0)))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language you are using so I may be incorrect, but I don't think you account for integer multiples of 100 (not leap years unless they are also integer multiples of 400) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar for example: 2100 is not a leap year

Comment: You are right! I will fix it. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Python <strike>64</strike> <strike>61</strike> 59

```
(62648012>>m*2&3)+28+(m==2and y%4==0*(y%100>0 or y%400==0))
```

Based on olivecoder's solution, but accounting for [multiples of 100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar).

Answer (score 2):

### VBA, 84

```
28+Val(Mid("303232332323",M,1))-(M=2 And Y Mod 4=0 And (Y Mod 100>0 Or Y Mod 400=0))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 50 <s>54</s> <s>57</s>

```
29+{2:y%(y%25and 4or 16)and-1}.get(m,(1&m^m>>3)+1)
```

with inspiration from mob, and the interesting fact, that
a dict saves 1 byte in contrast to m==2and(..)or(...)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <strike>97 91 83 82 78</strike> 76

A bit long, but gets the job done.

> d
>      =
>      
>       
>        y
>        ~
>        Divisible
>        ~
>        #
>       
>       &
>      
>     
>     ;
>     
>      30
>      +
>      
>       
>        {
>        
>         1
>         ,
>         
>          
>           Boole
>           [
>           
>            
>             d
>             @
>             400
>            
>            ∨
>            
>             (
>             
>              
>               d
>               @
>               4
>              
>              ∧
>              
>               ¬
>               
>                d
>                @
>                100
>               
>              
>             
>             )
>            
>           
>           ]
>          
>          -
>          2
>         
>         ,
>         1
>         ,
>         0
>         ,
>         1
>         ,
>         0
>         ,
>         1
>         ,
>         1
>         ,
>         0
>         ,
>         1
>         ,
>         0
>         ,
>         1
>        
>        }
>       
>       [
>       
>        [
>        m
>        ]
>       
>       ]

Answer (score 1):

#### VB.net (<strike>89</strike> 81c)

shame about the date function restriction as **VB.net** at only **(21c)**

```
Date.DaysInMonth(y,m)
```

may have won one for a change. DAMN YOU!

So current best is **89c**

<strike>{0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}(m)+(If( m=2 AndAlso (y Mod 4)=0 AndAlso (y Mod 400)>0,1,0)</strike>

```
{0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}(m)+(If( m=2 And (y Mod 4)=0 And (y Mod 400)>0,1,0)
```

Comment: if we ignore the restriction on YDM, then I can beat that with **Excel** at only 19 characters with `=DAY(DATE(y,m+1,0))` :)

Comment: Importing the Namespace System.Date would mean you can remove the first 5 chars, so that brings it down to 16c